# Credentials must be an instance of Aws\\Credentials\\CredentialsInterface error on PHP SDK with SQS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to delete a message from `SQS` in AWS using the php SDK. I have the following configuration.

```
$sqsClient = new SqsClient([
            'version' => '2012-11-05',
            'region'  => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => KEY,
                'secret' => SECRET
            ]
        ]);
```

Then I am trying to delete like the following :

```
$sqsClient->deleteMessage([
                'QueueUrl' => quque-url
                'ReceiptHandle' => handle
            ]);
```

I am getting the following error on initialization :

`Credentials must be an instance of Aws\\Credentials\\CredentialsInterface, an associative array that contains \"key\", \"secret\", and an optional \"token\" key-value pairs, a credentials provider function, or false."`

The credentials I am using is correct. Before I was not passing the config and then also the same error was appearing. How this can be fixed ?

Answer (score 10):

I found [this code example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_hardcoded.html) and I think your code is correct.

How about create instance of `Credentials`?

You can use these code for initiating instance.

```php
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials(KEY, SECRET);
$sqsClient = new SqsClient([
            'version' => '2012-11-05',
            'region'  => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => $credentials
        ]);
```

Check this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Credentials.Credentials.html).

And for security reason, I recommend that you'd better use credentials file or set environment variable.

I hope all is well.